# Mock open function calls nothing

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I have a problem with Mock open file testing. When im trying to get mock_calls it returns to me [call()], and when im doing assert_called_once_with i get an exception:
AssertionError: expected call not found.
Expected: open('test.txt', 'w')
Actual: open()

I really can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

Thats the code:

```
class TestFileData(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_save_data(self):

        m = mock_open()
        with patch('{}.open'.format('task_4'), new_callable=m, create=True) as f:
            with open('test.txt', 'w') as h:
                h.write('this is text')
                print(m.mock_calls)
                m.assert_called_once_with('test.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Please include whats the code for `mock_open().asser_called_once_with()` if its a library what library are you using.

Comment: from mock import patch, mock_open